# xUnit All Theories execute when in same class

Tags: c#, xunit.net, test-explorer

I am using xUnit v2.2.0 with xunit.runner.visualstudio v2.2.0 in VS 2015 Update 3.

When I right-click on one test in the Test Explorer to debug one Theory the runner executes both tests instead of the one I choose.

```
using WebPage.PageObjects;
using Tests.Data;
using System;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions;
using static Tests.Data.PasswordsData;

namespace xUnit.Net.Tests
{
    public class xUnit_POC: IDisposable
    {
        [Theory]
        [ExcelData(@"C:\TestScenarios.xls", "Select * from TestScenarios")]
        public void xUnit_ChangePassword_wXLS(string CurrentPassword, string NewPassword, string ExpectedResult)
        {
            // Test Code goes here...
        }

        [Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(PasswordsData))]
        public void xUnit_ChangePassword_wObject(PasswordsList testData)
        {
            // Test Code goes here...
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, when I separate them between two classes the only the test I choose to debug runs:

```
using WebPage.PageObjects;
using Tests.Data;
using System;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions;
using static Tests.Data.PasswordsData;

namespace xUnit.Net.Tests
{
    public class xUnit_POC 
    {
        public class TestWithObject : IDisposable
        {
            [Theory]
            [ClassData(typeof(PasswordsData))]
            public void xUnit_ChangePassword_wObject(PasswordsList testData)
            {
                // Test Code goes here...
            }
        }

        public class TestWithList : IDisposable
        {
            [Theory]
            [ExcelData(@"C:\TestScenarios.xls", "Select * from TestScenarios")]
            public void xUnit_ChangePassword_wXLS(string CurrentPassword, string NewPassword, string ExpectedResult)
            {
                // Test Code goes here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the normal behavior? If not, how can I fix this?